# match 2 files using awk when first file as key has multiple values

Tags: linux, awk

I have 2 files A & B.
And I'm using this command for matching:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3","$2; next}; $1 in a {print $0a[$1]}' A B
```

Problem is file A has repeated entries in column 1. Now there'll be many values for a single key in array 'a'. Will this command print all the values or first value only present in array a?

Comment: adding sample input lines from A and B and expected output would help...

Comment: Why not try it and thereby answer your own question?